# Create a method that lists instances that were set to True in a previous class

Tags: python, class, methods

I have the following code that records job candidates' personal details in a class `Employee`:

```
class Employee:
   def __init__(self, name, role, id):
      self.name = name
      self.role = role
      self.id = id
      self.interviewed = False

   def __str__(self):
      text = f'Candidate {self.name}; {self.id}. '
      if self.interviewed == False:
         return text + 'Not interviewed yet.'
      else:
         return text + 'Interviewed.'

   def interview(self):
      self.interviewed = True
```

I also have another class `Database` that lists all the candidates in a database for a particular employer:

```
class Database:
   def __init__(self, company, employer):
      self.company = company
      self.employer = employer
      self.candidates = []

   def __str__(self):
      text = f'{The hiring company is {self.company} and the employers name is {self.employer}'
      return text

   def add_candidate(self, candidate):
      self.candidates.append(candidate)
```

Now, if we record personal details of two candidates in the `class Employee` and add them to the `class Database` using the method `add_candidate`, how do I create a new method called `list_interviewed_candidates(self)` in the `class Database` that will print all candidates that have `self.interviewed` set to True?

This is what I tried:

```
class Database:
   def __init__(self, company, employer):
      self.company = company
      self.employer = employer
      self.candidates = []

   def __str__(self):
      text = f'{The hiring company is {self.company} and the employers name is {self.employer}'
      return text

   def add_candidate(self, candidate):
      self.candidates.append(candidate)

   def list_interviewed_candidates(self):
      for employee in self.candidates:
         if employee.interviewed == True:
            return employee
```

But that doesn't work. I have also tried list comprehension but it seems I just cannot access the boolean value that was set in the first class. Ideally, the output should look something like this:

```
database1 = Database('Google', 'Jack H')
print(database1) 
'The hiring company is Google and the employers name is Jack H'

candidate1 = Employee('Anna S', 'web-designer', 12)
database1.add_candidate(candidate1)
print(database1.list_interviewed_candidates()) 
[]

candidate1.interview()
print(database1.list_interviewed_candidates()) 
['Candidate Ana S; 12 - Interviewed']
```

Comment: Did you mean: `return [employee for employee in self.candidates if employee.interviewed]`?

Comment: "I have also tried list comprehension" what did you try and why didn't it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Database.list_interviewed_candidates` method you are returning the first employee that was interviewed. Keep in mind that `return` exits from the current function (method in this case) as soon as is hit.

So it starts looking at your candidates and as soon as one interviewed is found, it returns that one.

You probably want to gather them all in a list and return that:

```
   def list_interviewed_candidates(self):
      retval = []
      for employee in self.candidates:
         if employee.interviewed == True:
            retval.append(employee)
      return retval
```

Something pretty interesting you could also use is [`yield`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do):

```
   def list_interviewed_candidates(self):
      for employee in self.candidates:
         if employee.interviewed == True:
            yield employee
```

Which... you can try by doing:

```
print(list(database1.list_interviewed_candidates()))
```

Pretty cool. This opens the really fun world of iterators!

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension works, but realize `__str__` is used by `print` but `__repr__` is used for items displayed in a list.  `__repr__` is also used if `__str__` isn't defined.

Try the following, but change `__str__` to `__repr__` in `Employee`:

```py
def list_interviewed_candidates(self):
    return [employee for employee in self.candidates if employee.interviewed]
```

Then:

```py
database1 = Database('Google', 'Jack H')
print(database1) 

candidate1 = Employee('Anna S', 'web-designer', 12)
candidate2 = Employee('Mark T', 'pythonista', 13)
database1.add_candidate(candidate1)
database1.add_candidate(candidate2)
print(database1.list_interviewed_candidates()) 

candidate1.interview()
candidate2.interview()
print(database1.list_interviewed_candidates())
```

Outputs:

```
The hiring company is Google and the employers name is Jack H
[]
[Candidate Anna S; 12. Interviewed., Candidate Mark T; 13. Interviewed.]
```

Customize `__str__` and `__repr__` individually if you want differing output between direct `print` of `Employee` and how it is displayed in a list.